# Capturing IP Camera URL for audio feed with Wireshark

Tags: wireless-networking, wireshark, audio-recording, audio-streaming, ip-camera

I have three IP cameras (momentum - MOCAM3) and all works fine. I was able to get them connected to my home ISP router, registred with my data mobile phone and I can access them remotely this way.

I then setup iSpy for the server on my Windows 10 PC on this same network and determined the URL for the streamed video with built in iSpy options and I'm able to capture the video stream on motion detection and save all that as a file saved on my computer.

For some reason I cannot find the audio stream URL to plug into iSpy to capture this data and I'm also unable to get the audio capture with VLC either for quicker testing as I cannot determine the URL I think.

I contacted the IP Cam vendor and they said, "sorry, our product is not supported to work with third party software so we cannot help you".

- > I was able to get the video stream captured with iSpy even though they
  >   don't support it so if I can determine the audio URL I should be able to
  >   get that too. I was also able to capture both audio and video with
  >   other devices I used as IP cams that are older droid data phones with
  >   software installed and all that.

If I connect to the MOCAM3 cameras with the app on my mobile phone (the only supported method to manage these) it allows me to hear audio and turn sensors on and off.

**My Question:** Since these IP cameras are connected to my ISP router via wifi on my same network as the iSpy server then could I potentially capture any URL or other type of paths to use to capture the feed since the vendor will not tell me? I think it connects with rtsp based on the URL for the video I can capture or connect to network stream option in VLC (rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.1.10/H264/sub). Is there any way if not Wireshark for me to determine the audio URL or whatever I need to capture or control it if need on these devices?